# KICad simulation issues

Tags: kicad

I've been having issues with the Spice simulator showing no values, and i got it to show a graph, but the graph makes no sense. It's a simple RC circuit, but the graph that i'm getting, looks like this;[image]

It is also missing any type of scaling on the Y-axis.

Software is KICad 6.0

Help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a question to bring up on the KiCad forums or something, not here.

Comment: You might want to connect the resistor to the capacitor.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  They are connected.  That small black box is for the `Vcap` label.  It's the label that's not connected, which is why his red plot is called `V(Net-(C1-Pad1))` instead of `V(/Vcap)`.

Comment: @SteKulov Ah. That makes sense.

Comment: If the source is a simple DC (as I see it) then what you see is just numerical noise, since there are no dynamics involved, and the Y axis has no numbers because it probably makes no sense to have any for 1e-15 or less differences. Try making the source a sine, or a pulse, give it some variation.